# Yum - testing if something is installed and then using that from a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, fedora, yum

Is there a good way to use Yum to test if something is installed (true of false) and then use that answer in a Bash script?

Answer (score 4):

It's faster to query using `rpm` instead.

```
if rpm -q somepackage &> /dev/null
then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: You can make that even faster with `rpm -q somepackage --nodigest  --nosignatures`.

Answer (score 1):

if you know a bit of python you could do it very easy - yum has pre/post filters that can be enabled you can even make your own plugin.

from shell just look for any lines that will be the output from your query.

pack = yum info package | wc -l

if [ "$pack" != '' ];

then

```
do something
```

else

```
do something else
```

fi

Answer (score 1):

I typically test for the results of the package, usually a file on the file-system that is installed.  Something like:

```
[ ! -f /usr/bin/apg ] && yum -y install apg
```

This requires no RPM database lookup, so it's **very** light-weight.